# Regex in XPath expression

Tags: ruby, regex, selenium, xpath

I have some HTML code:

```
<div>
  <div id="order-1"></div>
  <div id="order-2"></div>
</div>
```

I want to find all DIVs with IDs 'order'.
In Ruby I try

```
divs = driver.find_elements :xpath, '//div[matches(@id, "order-[0-9]")]'
```

But Selenium gives a error

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector:
>   Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //div[matches(@id, "order-[0-9]")] because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//div[matches(@id, "order-[0-9]")]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Why?

Comment: The `matches` function was introduced in XPath 2.0 in 2007 but unfortunately many XPath implementations remain XPath 1.0 implementations without support for that function and others introduced in XPath 2.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanx! Selenium used XPath 1.0. I try //div[starts-with(@id, 'order-')]. It's work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`starts-with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with), though that does not check for a number at the end of the id:

```
//div[starts-with(@id,"order-")]
```